# Animate inline svg left to right (the image) smoothly without moving image?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate an inline SVG image illustrating waves that go up and down. Have an image where I have to animate it so it looks like the ship sails on the waves.

Can't seem to make it right, have looked at the transform with the translateX, but then the image(SVG) is moving. Isn't it possible to just move the waves from left to right in an infinite loop without moving the picture, and make it so it is smooth?

[image: ship sailing on the waves]

**HTML**

```
<div class="spinner">
      <img class="ship" src="./assets/ship.svg" />
      <span class="waves">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 146 37" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <g id="Loader" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="red" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <g id="Artboard-Copy" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero">
              <g id="Group-Copy">
                      <path d="M0,5 C7.57597216,5 7.24715338,-9.32587341e-15 14.6,-9.32587341e-15 C21.9528466,-9.32587341e-15 21.9335777,5 29.2,5 C36.4664223,5 36.5256034,-9.04831765e-15 43.8,-9.32587341e-15 C51.0743966,-9.32587341e-15 51.2650965,5 58.4,5 C65.5349035,5 65.6270419,-9.04831765e-15 73,-9.32587341e-15 C80.3729581,-9.32587341e-15 80.2196466,5 87.6,5 C94.9803534,5 94.9224659,-9.32587341e-15 102.2,-9.32587341e-15 C109.477534,-9.32587341e-15 109.321471,5 116.8,5 C124.278529,5 124.275217,-9.32587341e-15 131.4,-9.32587341e-15 C138.524783,-9.32587341e-15 138.613807,5 146,5 L146,37 L0,37 L0,5 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
                  </g>
              </g>
          </g>
      </svg>
    </span>      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spinner {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding: 0.5rem;

  .ship {
    animation: bop 0.58s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .waves {
    position: absolute;
    width: 146px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    animation: sail 6s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes bop {
    to {
      transform: translateY(-7%);
    }
  }

  @keyframes sail {
    to {
      transform: translateX(50px);
    }
  }
```

Please note that the color of the waves will be changed to fill=inherit, equal to the grey background-color. Just made it so you could see it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will need a slightly bigger path than the viewBox width. In this case I'm using viewBox="0 0 **116.8** 37"  while the width of your path (calculated with `wave.getBBox()`) is 146 units. In order to understand what happens please add `overflow: visible;` to the svg element.

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow: visible;*/
}
#wave {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: sail 2s  ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes sail {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-29.2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 116.8 37" width="200">
        <path fill="red" d="M0,5 C7.57597216,5 7.24715338,-9.32587341e-15 14.6,-9.32587341e-15 C21.9528466,-9.32587341e-15 21.9335777,5 29.2,5 C36.4664223,5 36.5256034,-9.04831765e-15 43.8,-9.32587341e-15 C51.0743966,-9.32587341e-15 51.2650965,5 58.4,5 C65.5349035,5 65.6270419,-9.04831765e-15 73,-9.32587341e-15 C80.3729581,-9.32587341e-15 80.2196466,5 87.6,5 C94.9803534,5 94.9224659,-9.32587341e-15 102.2,-9.32587341e-15 C109.477534,-9.32587341e-15 109.321471,5 116.8,5 C124.278529,5 124.275217,-9.32587341e-15 131.4,-9.32587341e-15 C138.524783,-9.32587341e-15 138.613807,5 146,5 L146,37 L0,37 L0,5 Z" id="wave"></path>
</svg>
```